# Sum of series with non-common ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

In the following series:

$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n*\frac{1}{2^n}$

I've found that the series converges to 2 by looking it up but how would one calculate the summation? You can't use the formula for a geometric sum because the series' terms don't differ by a common ratio. I'm sure I'm just missing something but it's been a while since I've done series. Thanks!

Comment: ooh that is a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you list out the terms according to the given general term by plugging in different values of $n$, you would find that it is an Arithmetico - Geometrtic Progression (AGP).

Let $$S = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n*\frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$\implies S = \frac12 + \frac{2}{2^2} + \frac{3}{2^3} +  .....$$

$$\implies \frac{S}{2} = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{2}{2^3} + \frac{3}{2^4} + $$ 
[After shifting the terms on the RHS by one place to the right.]

Subtracting; 
$$\implies \frac{S}{2} = \frac12 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} + ....$$
which yields $$\frac{S}{2} = 1$$ 
and thus $$S = 2$$

Comment: What are the rules again when subtracting infinite sums? Is it okay to do it as long as you're not cancelling stuff out?

Comment: @Anthony:  IIRC it's a legitimate move when the series are absolutely convergent.  In this case, both $S$ and $S/2$ can be seen to be absolutely convergent by applying the ratio test.

Comment: @Anthony I forgot to mention the fact that $\frac{S}{2}$ has been written after one right shift, which leads to the subsequent computation. Edited the post now.

Answer (score 4):

Let 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x},
$$
assuming that $|x| < 1$.  Then we have
$$
x f'(x) = x \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n x^n,
$$
but also
$$
x f'(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
$$
Thus, 
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty n x^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$
for all $|x| < 1$.  In particular, with $x = 1/2$, the series sums to 2, as you found.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks!